# STL connectivity check

Tags: mesh, openfoam

I'm trying to find a way to check if two stl's are coincident (python preferred).
Let's say I have to parts, a cube with a central cutout in the shape of a triangular pyramid, and a triangular pyramid that fits into that cutout.
The correct parts should fit, but an incorrect part (say if you put a cube into the cutout) should be flagged.

So far I have found no ways of doing this.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem. A far easier one that might already satisfy your use case is checking for the volume of the cut-out and the volume of the filling. They must coincide. (Of course, this is no guarantee for fitting, but perhaps a good first check.)

Comment: hi nico - yes, a hard problem which I tried to simplify in the example. in reality my STL's are not volumes fitting into one another, but boundaries (think tetris) between two parts.